# Test Method Called Without Having Argument In Test Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have a class which takes a message with payload String.
The payload is then split and used to create an Entity which is passed to DAOInterface to persist.

How can you test the call `daoInterface.insert(entity)` has been made?

To Mock the DAOInterface and then verify the call to DAO requires the entity in the test class i.e.

```
verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);
```

Is this bad design i.e. creating the entity at this stage? Should the Sting[] split be passed to the DAOImplementaion and initialized there. Example problem,

```
public class ServiceClass {

    @AutoWire
    private DAOInterface daoInterface;

    public void serviceMessage(Message<String> message) {

        MessageHeaders mh = new MessageHeaders(message.getHeaders());       
        String[] split = ((String) mh.get("payload")).split("_");

        code omitted
        ...

        String type = mh.get("WhatType");

        Entity entity = new Entity(split[0], split[1], split[2]);

        if (type.equals("one"))
        {
            daoInterface.insert(entity); //How to test?
        }
        else
        {
            if (type.equals("two"))
            {
                doaInterface.modify(entity); //How to test?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify with Mockito [Matchers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html).

If you only care that the method is called with *some* `Entity`, you can verify that with

```
verify(daoInterface).insert(any(Entity.class));
```

If you care about which `Entity`, and the `Entity` class has an `equals` method, you can make an entity that should be equal to the one created and verify with

```
verify(daoInterface).insert(eq(expectedEntity);
```

If it's more complex than either of these cases, you can also write your own argument matchers.

Comment: Thanks Don. Using the entities equals() method to verify the initialised entity is as expected and the insert method is called is what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is injecting another collaborator to the service which will transform *payload* to *Entity*. This way you can keep control on object creation ([Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)). Something like the example below injected to the `ServiceClass` should do the job:

```
interface PayloadTransformer {
    public Entity transform(String payload);
}
```

This way your code will be easy to test and you split responsibilities which is usually a good thing. Have a look on [Single Responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Pushing transformation logic down to dao is almost never a good idea.

BTW. you can write `else if` without additional brackets and indentations. It's more readable like:

```
if (a) {
    // do something
} else if (b) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

The last advice ServiceClass is really poor name for class. The word class is redundant here. Just name it *Service*, *EntityService*, *MessageService* or something which fits your case well.
I wouldn't name field with suffix *Interface as well. Underneath is some implementation injected, I assume. Better name it *entityDao* or just *dao*. It's up to you though :)

Comment: The above code is just an example of the issue hence the names :)

Comment: "The easiest thing you can do is injecting another collaborator to the service"? IoC? a call to daoInterface.insert(entity) will still be required.

Comment: IoC - Inversion of Control. If you injected both dao and transformer to the service you would have control and access to everything you need on the test side. You could test interaction with specific instance not any Entity.class like in the answer you accepted. Those are basics of proper object oriented design.

Comment: The accepted answerer is not testing any entity it test if the call is made with a specific entity equal to the one you expect.

Comment: Inject another object `@AutoWired PayLoadTransformer paloadTransformer ... Entity entity = payloadTransformer.transform(payload); ... daoInterface.insert(entity);` In the test class you would then need to Mock both the transformer and the dao to verify both Entity and String `verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);` `verify(pInt).transform(payload);`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a test framework like [PowerMock,](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) you can [invoke private constructors and private methods](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation) in your test.  This makes it easy to inject mock objects like a mock `DAOInterface` so you can retrieve it later and test it's been called.

For example, in PowerMock, to call a private constructor:

```
public class ServiceClass{

        @Autowire
        private final DAOInterface dao;

        public ServiceClass() {
        }

        private ServiceClass(DAOInterface dao) {
                this.dao = dao;
        }


}
```

You simply do:

```
PrivateConstructorInstantiationDemo instance =  WhiteBox.invokeConstructor(
                                PrivateConstructorInstantiationDemo.class, 
                                new MockDAOInterface() );
```

So if you're using a dependency inject framework like above, this dovetails nicely.  You don't normally have the dependency injection working during test, since it usually requires booting a large chunk of code with a lot of configuration.

By adding a single private constructor, you avoid breaking encapsulation, but you can still inject your mock object into the code during test with a test framework like PowerMock.  This is considered best practice.

You could break encapsulation and add publicly accessible methods or ctors to the SeviceClass, but if you don't need them for your design it's not good practice to add them only for test.  That's why people put such effort into bypassing encapsulation in frameworks like Mockito and PowerMock.  It's not just a dodge around private code, it's because you want to keep the encapsulation while still being able to test.

EDIT:

If you're not familiar with making mock objects, you should do some Google searches on the subject.  It's very common and a good skill to have.  With the above code, you could make your own mock object.  But making mocks is so common that most test frameworks will do this for you.

For example, in PowerMock, I just looked at their [page on making mocks here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).  You can make a mock like this

```
DAOInteface myMock = createMock(DAOInterface.class);
```

You can then ask the mock to verify that methods are called:

```
expect(myMock.someMethod());
```

Now the mock 'expects' that method to be called, and if it isn't, it'll generate an error for your test.  Pretty sweet actually.

You can also return values from a call:

```
expect(myMock.insert()).andReturn("Test succeeded");
```

so your code would then see the value "Test succeeded" when it called that method.  I don't see that 'insert' does return a value, that's just an example.

Comment: If such tricks are needed to test quite simple class it rather means something is wrong with the design.

Comment: Uh, no.  Stuff like this is needed all the time.

Comment: If your testing some code you can't change then yes. Otherwise it clearly shows you should refactor. I mostly write tests with Groovy/Spock, which means I can access anything what's private (that's a known Groovy feature/bug). Despite that I never do this as it's poor practise. You shouldn't need to test/assert directly anything what's private.

Comment: Encapsulation is a good thing.  There's no reason to break encapsulation if the actual design doesn't require it.  His design has a private dao.  Don't make that public with a ctor or public setter if you don't need to.  Since we have a test framework that allows us to bypass encapsulation, then we use it.  Tool use is good.

Comment: BTW. your answer doesn't address the question. For my understating,  problem lays not with mocking dao but testing interaction with specific argument. However from the test level there is no control on the argument instantiation. Thus why it can't be tested even with PowerMock, I guess.

Comment: Encapsulation is a good thing, agreed. Testing encapsulated things not. You should test contract not inner mechanism of a class. Besides our discussion is pointless as that's not the problem stated in the question. DAO field is private but sample code doesn't show where it is being instantiated. I'm assuming it's injected.

Comment: @cID: add a private ctor then so you can inject it with your test framework.  I'll edit my code.

Comment: How does this verify the call to `verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);` has been made. @Mock DAOinterface will give a mock object but there is no way of instantiating the entity in the test class.

Comment: Well, the object you inject you could verify the call.  You'll need to make a special mock object yourself, or you could use a test framework like PowerMock or Mockito to automate it.  I'll add some code in a sec.

Comment: The problem is not Mocking the DAOInterface if you look at the above example the code `verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);` is obviously implying the use of a Test Framework such as PowerMock or Mockito
'@Mock
DAOInterface
Mockito.verify(daoInterface).insert(entity);'

To call the verify method you require an argument of Type entity which you dont have in the test class.

Comment: Most mock frameworks ignore the parameters to a call.  You could call 'insert` with any type of entity.  You pass in the string that makes the entity so I assume you have control over it.  If not, you'll have to show the code you use.  The question was "how to verify that insert() is being called" and I showed that.

Comment: Mockito certainly doesn't ignore parameters.